# Gunicorn doesn't log real ip from nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I run a django app via gunicorn, supervisor and nginx as reverse proxy and struggle to make my gunicorn access log show the actual ip instead of 127.0.0.1:

Log entries look like this at the moment:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2014:15:46:52] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.0" ...
```

supervisord.conf

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/opt/middleware/bin/gunicorn --chdir /opt/middleware -c /opt/middleware/gunicorn_conf.py middleware.wsgi:application 
stdout_logfile=/var/log/middleware/gunicorn.log
```

gunicorn_conf.py

```
#!python
from os import environ
from gevent import monkey
import multiprocessing
monkey.patch_all()

bind = "0.0.0.0:9000"
x_forwarded_for_header = "X-Real-IP"
policy_server = False
worker_class = "socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker"   
accesslog = '-'
```

my nginx module conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /opt/middleware;
    index index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

      }
    }
```

I tried all sorts of combinations in the location {} block, but can't see that it makes any difference. Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that you need to configure [`gunicorn`'s logging](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/0.17.0/configure.html#logging), because it will (by default) not display any custom headers.

From the documentation, we find out that the default access log format is controlled by [`access_log_format`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/0.17.0/configure.html#access-log-format) and is set to the following:

```
"%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
```

where:

- `h` is the remote address
- `l` is `-` (not used)
- `u` is `-` (not used, reserved)
- `t` is the time stamp
- `r` is the status line
- `s` is the status of the request
- `b` is length of response
- `f` is referrer
- `a` is user agent

You can also customize it with the following extra variables that are not used by default:

- `T` - request time (in seconds)
- `D` - request time (in microseconds)
- `p` - the process id
- `{Header}i` - request header (custom)
- `{Response}o` - response header (custom)

To `gunicorn`, all requests are coming from nginx so it will display that as the remote IP. To get it to log any custom headers (what you are sending from `nginx`) you'll need to adjust this parameter and add the appropriate variables, in your case you would set it to the following:

```
%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s" "%({X-Real-IP}i)s"
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would replace the value of %(h). Works great, but I can't figure out why it's always inserting a newline after wherever I put {X-Real-IP} :-/

Comment: None of this worked for me. NOTE: The string above needs to be surrounded in single quotes, or bash will not accept it in the parameter list. In the end I used uWsgi. I started with gunicorn because I thought it was simple, but by the time you set up supervisord and have to deal with it not passing information easily to django, uwsgi is a much better option.

Comment: If you want to use it as a command flag you should use `--access-logformat`

Answer (score 0):

Note that headers containing `-` should be referred to here by replacing `-` with `_`, thus `X-Forwarded-For` becomes `%({X_Forwarded_For}i)s`.

Comment: That doesn't seem true for gunicorn 20.1.0.